# Calculate TVA Tax of multiple product in one code line (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tax

I've a list of dict contains products :

```
products = [{'name' : 'art1','amount':2000, 'qty':2, 'tax':['tax_15', 'tva']} ,
    {'name' : 'art2','amount':2500, 'qty':3, 'tax':['tax_15', 'timbre']},
    {'name' : 'art3','amount':3000, 'qty':4, 'tax':['tva']}]
```

and a list of dict contains taxes :

```
taxes = [{'name' : 'tax_15','amount':15} ,
    {'name' : 'tva','amount':17},
    {'name' : 'timbre','amount':10}]
```

I want to calculate tva of all products, in this exemple, tva exists just in art1 and art3, in this case:
`tva = (2000 * 17%) + (3000 * 17%)`

I want to calculate the **tva** in one single line of python code, I tried with this line:

```
sum([t['amount']*t['qty']*tax_of_tva_if_exist_in_this_product  for t in products])
```

Comment: Is the product name in the first list dict,  and tax name in the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard search, I find the response :

```
sum([item['amount']*tax['amount'] for item in products if 'tva' in item['tax'] for tax in taxes if tax['name']=='tva'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of dict contains taxes has only two values. You can use a `dict` instead of `list`. Rebuild your list of taxes to dict of taxes, which use `name` as key

```
taxes_dict = {}
for tax in taxes:
    taxes_dict[tax['name']] = tax
```

So you can calculate the tva in one line so:

```
sum([t[amount]*t[qty]*taxes_dict['tva']['amount'] if 'tva' in t['tax'] else 0 for t in products])
```

P/S: please check your list again. `name`, `qty` and `tax` should may be `'name'`, `'qty'` and `'tax'`

Comment: If i have a dict in place list, that not a problem

Comment: So if you want to calculate only `tva`, why did you need a list?

Comment: Because, one product can has more than one tax

Comment: And `tva` is just exemple of tax, my objectif is calculate tva, and timbre and tax_15 of all products

Comment: It means you need to search the tax value from `taxes`. `dict` hat better performance than `list` by searching.

Comment: So i have edited my answer. It uses your original `list` to build a new `dict` for searching.

Comment: I know, because of that i have created a new dict from the taxes_list. I didn't edit it.

Comment: Thank you very match julivico for your help, I think use a normal function with more than one single line

Comment: Okay, No problem ;)